# Cronjob not working and not logging

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Hi i have a Problem with my Cronjob

So what im tring to do is, i have a Raspberry Pi with network monitoring software on it. I want to bring him to a customer network and at night it should upload the logs to our nextcloud server.

So for the sync job i use owncloudcmd. I worte a .sh and tested it and it works.

So i created a Cronjob that should sync every 5 min for testing.

Now it is not uploading and in the syslog ist also not mentioned.

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /root/checkconfig.sh

5 * * * * /root/owncloudsync.sh
```

those are the Cronjobs.
the one above should check and send the ip it works fine, but was not wirten by me.

```
#Dieses file Synchroniesiert alle Ergebnise mit nextcloud

# Um Datenverlust zu vermeiden werden alle datein erst
# in ein eignes verzeichnis kopiert

cp -r /var/log /root/owncloudsync

# Nun Pushen wir diese Daten in die Nextcloud

owncloudcmd --user login --password password  --exclude /home/savecall/sync-exclude.lst /root/owncloudsync https://example.de
```

Sorry comments are in German but should be easy to read anyway.

the first command copys the files just to be safe that they dont get lost.
the second should push the data.

But it is not uploading and not coping with Cron, the syslog dosen't say anything about that.

if i try it manually it works. Sorry im new to this stuff.

Comment: Did you get any mail from cron?

Comment: Quick guess: file access permissions? What crontab is that?

Comment: no the file runs in root cron an was created with cron

Comment: Jobs under cron run with a very cut-down environment. Your PATH (for example) will be minimal. Amend your cron job with a following 2>&1 >/tmp/mycron.log (or similar) and that should capture what's going on

Answer (score 0):

```
5 * * * * /root/owncloudsync.sh
```

Will run /root/owncloudsync.sh at exact minute 5 for every hour.

If you want /root/owncloudsync.sh to run ervery 5 min, the crontab should be:

```
*/5 * * * * /root/owncloudsync.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
5 * * * * /root/owncloudsync.sh
```

is for every hour past 5 minutes jobs.

for running cronjob try below code

```
*/5 * * * * /root/owncloudsync.sh
```